# Magnetic force is a no work force. Why is it doing work here?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

Here the rod is projected with a velocity $v_0$ . Due to change in flux in the loop, we have an induced emf in the loop, which induces a current $i$ that exerts a force $Bil$ where $B$ is the magnetic field,  $l$ is the length of the rod. Here clearly the energy of the system has been lowered, as the rod slows down to a stop. So definitely a work has been done. But a magnetic field is a zero work force. So what exactly performs the work here? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: The work is done by the force pushing the rod.

Comment: @trula there is no force pushing tje rod here. The rod is projected at v0 speed

Comment: try calculating the work done in producing the current in the wire

Comment: No, here due to the motion of the rod in the field an emf is generated which creates a current, this current causes another magnetic force causing the rod to slow down. The change in kinetic **of** rod is $1/2mv_0^2$, but since there is a current flowing now what is its energy? You can get it by $W=\int I^2Rdt$

Comment: btw this exact problem is given in Griffiths 4rth ed., Problem no 7.7

Comment: To keep the wire moving at $v_0$, you must apply a force.

Answer (score 3):

This answer adds little – except, perhaps, some linking passages – to the comments already made.

The rod's velocity is shared by the free electrons in it, and therefore these experience a magnetic Lorentz force along the rod. The resultant of this force and the electrical resistive forces is zero when these electrons have a steady drift velocity *along* the rod.

This velocity component along the rod gives the free electrons a magnetic Lorentz force at right angles to the rod, slowing it down (because these forces are 'passed on' to the rod by the electrical forces that keep the electrons in the rod).

But the slowing down implies a loss of kinetic energy. Surely magnetic forces do no work, so they can't be responsible for this. The kinetic energy is transferred to random internal (thermal) energy of the electrical circuit of which the rod is a part. The forces involved here are those between the free electrons and the ions they collide with, not the magnetic Lorentz force.